# Modify only the object of the clone

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an array of profiles, and I want to edit one of them to set the value of a property, so I created a clone using cloneDeep:

```
 let newProfiles = []
 let newProfile = cloneDeep(this.profiles.find(p => p.id === data.profileId));
 newProfile.hasUser = true;
 newProfiles.push(newProfile);
```

So this is creating clone of the global object filtering a profile by Id, so this works well, now I want only to modify the object I modified in the original list if I use it like this:

```
this.profiles = newProfiles;
```

It removes all the profiles and just takes the new one; how can I keep with the full list and only modify the new profile I modified?

Comment: Why do you need to clone the object if you're just going to modify and replace it later?

Comment: Yes, if I do not do it it throws an error: `Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'hasUser' of object '[object Object]'
TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'hasUser' of object '[object Object]'` @vera.

Answer (score 0):

If you replace the old version of the user's profile anyway, why not edit the profile in place?

`this.profiles.find(p => p.id === data.profileId).hasUser = true;`

I don't know why you would use `clonedeep` here, but if you want your code to work the way you started to solve this, you would need to remove the profile you've updated first and then `push` the updated version into the array.

Comment: If I try to do that I get an error: `Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'hasUser' of object '[object Object]'
TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'hasUser' of object '[object Object]'` because it is getting this.profiles as readonly

Comment: Then copy the profiles first: `const profileCopy = [...this.profiles]`. The rest would be the same: `profileCopy.find(p => p.id === data.profileId).hasUser = true;`

Comment: If I try change the value of the copy as: `profileCopy.find(p => p.id === data.profileId).hasUser = true;`, it throws exactly the same error as the global one

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve this I removed the profile first then reassign to list as:

```
let newProfiles = cloneDeep(this.profiles);
     let profileEdited = newProfiles.find(p => p.id === data.profileId)

     //delete profile from copy
     var currentProfile = newProfiles.indexOf(profileEdited);
     newProfiles.splice(currentProfile, 1);

     //re-asign profile
     profileEdited.hasUser = true;
     newProfiles.push(profileEdited);

     this.profiles = newProfiles;
```

Comment: This works because you're removing the type assertion. This would work just as well: `(this.profiles as any).find((p) => p.id === data.profileId).hasUser = true;`